# MS Word Plugin, Adding a button which pops up on right click on selected text

Tags: c#, word-2007, shared-addin

I am working on a shared addin for MS Word 2007. I would like to add a button which pops up when selected text is right clicked. The attached snapshot should make this clear.

Currently, the user has to select the text and then click a button on a custom control. It would be a lot easier if after selecting the text, s/he could right click it and press the relevant button in the popup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this can be done...

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar cellbar = diff.CommandBars["Text"];
Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton button = (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton)cellbar.FindControl(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 0, "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
if (button == null)
{
   // add the button
   button = (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton)cellbar.Controls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, cellbar.Controls.Count + 1, true);
   button.Caption = "My Right Click Menu Item";
   button.BeginGroup = true;
   button.Tag = "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU";
   button.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(MyButton_Click);
}
```

Comment: This also adds in the button in the context menu, not the mini toolbar.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, but it adds the check to avoid duplication, otherwise you get multiple buttons, one with every new instance.
@Brandon Yes, but this is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the correct contextmenu. The following link describes in words (no source code) how this can be achieved:

[Shared Addin using Word](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/c2e20f36-35cb-4c2d-b9a4-b464fc7c9989/)

Maybe this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/62240ece-ab2d-4f28-b317-e6bd76f34000/) might help a little with the coding. I haven't tried it out myself, but it might point into the right direction.

Good luck! :)

**Edit:**

Does it have to be the ribbon style context menu or would a button within the normal context menu be enough?
In case the normal menu would be ok, you might use this way (C#):

```
 Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar cb = this.Application.CommandBars["Text"];

 Office.CommandBarControl newButton = cb.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, missing);  
 newButton.Caption = "Test";
 newButton.Visible = true;
 newButton.Enabled = true;
```

You can do this with VSTO, I'm not so sure if it works exactly the same way with the shared Add-In technology, but maybe it does help ;)

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338198.aspx) -

> You cannot modify the Mini toolbar programmatically.

a little over halfway down the doc.  Search on mini toolbar.

Edit:
The popup you have circled in the image above doesn't appear on right-click, it appears on highlight.  The context menu (below the selected text) could have your custom functionality, but not in the mini toolbar.

Comment: I get the popup on right click as well as highlight (Word 2007).

Comment: True.  I didn't realize it popped up on right-click as well as highlight.

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.docmanagement/browse_thread/thread/cf55d996b3f51a06/65b2bad22e2a3583?lnk=st&q=Removing+Items+from+Word+2007 is how to do it in VBA.  It is very similar using COM and probably creating a word add-in (I have not tried it though)  You basically need to find the context menu control and add an item to it (your function).