# How to add on mouse hover effect in Word 2010 addin

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-addins

I wish to add text to the bottom of the font hover menu in word add-in:

[image: This is the menu i want to use]

But i cant find any documentation regarding this specific menu.

**ADDED**

My goal is to get an onmousehover effect while hovering on selected text, and since Selection doesnt provide any event i figured that the mini menu could be my solution.

Comment: I developing for Word 2010 if it matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called `Word Mini Toolbar` (naming is important to get the right search results - tip, always find adequate names:).

Anyway I think you're out of luck, I've never seen anything related to that (I know how you can change the context menu, that's no problem). And frankly it doesn't seem very likely, as that seems like a 'cute little' toolbar that's specifically formatted to fit small format, size/looks.

Check this MS link [Developer Overview of the User Interface for the 2007 Microsoft Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338198.aspx)

And somewhere inside it says

> You cannot modify the Mini toolbar programmatically.

And this question/answers confirm that pretty much
[MS Word Plugin, Adding a button which pops up on right click on selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684438/ms-word-plugin-adding-a-button-which-pops-up-on-right-click-on-selected-text/715944#715944)

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check the solution marked there as accepted first and ill try to extend my question in order to clarify the goal. @NSGaga

Comment: PS I am targeting MS Word 2010

Comment: you're welcome - but it's not really a solution - that's for context menu only (OP accepted himself:) - I linked directly to the best comment there - which confirms it isn't possible unfortunately.